# Code will not write array to sheet but works for single variable

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I  have a 6 sheet workbook and am trying to write an array to one of the sheets. The code runs without error but the array doesn't actually write to the sheet.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Run()
    Dim ItemNames(260) As Variant
    Dim ItemNamesEng(260) As Variant
    Dim Sizes() As Variant
    Dim SizesNames() As Variant
    Dim Colors() As Variant
    Dim ColorsNames() As Variant
    Dim ColorsResults(260) As Variant
    Dim SizesResults(260) As Variant
    Dim UnitCode(260) As Variant
    Dim Serial(260) As Variant
    Dim Expiry(260) As Variant
    Dim SalePrice(260) As Variant
    Dim BulkPrice(260) As Variant
    Dim DistPrice(260) As Variant
    Dim OpeningBalance(260) As Variant
    Dim CostPrice(260) As Variant
    Dim ExpiryDate(260) As Variant
    Dim GroupCodeA(260) As Variant
    Dim SupplierNumA(260) As Variant
    Dim SupplierPrice(260) As Variant
    
    NumItems = Range("NumOfColors") * Range("NumOfSizes")
    SupplierName = Range("SupplierName")
    SupplierNum = Range("SupplierNum")
    GroupCode = Range("GroupCode")
    Cost = Range("CostPrice")
    Sale = Range("SalePrice")
    ModelName = Range("ModelName")
    Sizes() = Range("Sizes2P")
    SizesNames() = Range("SizesNames")
    Colors() = Range("Colors2P")
    ColorsNames = Range("ColorsNames")
    
    k = 1
        For i = 1 To Range("NumOfColors")
            For j = 1 To Range("NumOfSizes")
                ItemNames(k) = SupplierName & " " & ModelName & " " & ColorsNames(i, 1) & " " & SizesNames(j, 1)
                ItemNamesEng(k) = ItemNames(k)
                ColorsResults(k) = ColorsNames(i, 1)
                SizesResults(k) = SizesNames(j, 1)
                UnitCode(k) = 1
                Serial(k) = 0
                Expiry(k) = 0
                SalePrice(k) = Sale
                BulkPrice(k) = Sale
                DistPrice(k) = Sale
                OpeningBalance(k) = 0
                CostPrice(k) = Cost
                ExpiryDate(k) = 0
                GroupCodeA(k) = GroupCode
                SupplierNumA(k) = SupplierNum
                SupplierPrice(k) = Cost
                k = k + 1
            Next j
        Next i
        Sheets("ProducedData").Range("B3").Value = ItemNames
        
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried B3:B263 and it didn't work either

Comment: That is because the array you have is horizontal not vertical.  You will need to transpose it.

Comment: Also note that the lower bound of `ItenNames` is *zero*, not one. So the first element of `ItemNames` is empty.

Comment: Sheets("ProducedData").Range("B3:263").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ItemNames) Trying something like this? it's giving me an error but am I on the right track now @Scott Craner?

Comment: Try using `Application.Transpose` but realize that there is a limit to the number and size of items that can be transposed.  I usually use a 2D array with a single column: `Dim ItemNames(1 to 260, 1 to 1) As Variant`  Then I do not need to transpose.

Comment: Worked like a charm with the transpose! THANKS!!!!!! @Scott_Craner